# Skeleton Grid System - Change position of column when browser is shrunk

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a row of two columns and would like the right column (TEST NAME, CITY, ST, etc.) to appear above the left column when the browser is shrunk. As you can tell from the screenshots, when the browser is shrunk, the right column appears below the left column.

**Full size browser:**

[image: Full Size Browser]

**Shrunk to mobile size:**

[image: mobile size:]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->

<html lang="en"> 

<!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <!-- Basic Page Needs -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Campus Taps</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Mobile Specific Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/base.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/skeleton.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/layout.css">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">




</head>


<body>

<!--Start Navigation -->
<div class="band navigation">

<div class="container">
<div id="logo" class="two columns">
        <h1>DS</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="nav" class="fourteen columns">
        <ul><li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TEST</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div> <!-- End Band -->


<!--Start Content -->
<div class="band bar information">

<div class="container">

<div id="bar-logo" class="five columns">
    <img src="images/zwphoto.png" width="300" height="207">

</div>
<div id="google-maps" class="six columns offset-by-one">
    <img src="images/google-maps.png" width="608" height="212" />

</div>


<div id="bar-specials" class="ten columns alpha">
<h2 class="specials-title">SPECIALS</h2>
<div class="three columns"><h3>MONDAY</h3></div>
<div class="five columns"><p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum posuere massa eu commodo. Cras fermentum erat sed volutpat dignissim. Suspendisse pretium sem ut vestibulum mattis. Donec ultrices ipsum in molestie aliquam. Nulla tristique, nisl ac ultrices tempus, dolor leo convallis risus, sed porttitor magna sapien vitae neque. </p></div>
</div>

<div id="bar-information" class="six columns omega">
<h1>TEST NAME</h1>
<p>123 TEST Road</p>
<p>CITY, ST 1111111</p>
<p>(666) 666-6666</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum posuere massa eu commodo. Cras fermentum erat sed volutpat dignissim. Suspendisse pretium sem ut vestibulum mattis. Donec ultrices ipsum in molestie aliquam. Nulla tristique, nisl ac ultrices tempus, dolor leo convallis risus, sed porttitor magna sapien vitae neque. 

</p>
</div>



<div id="bar-specials" class="ten columns alpha">
<div class="three columns"><h3>TUESDAY</h3></div>
<div class="five columns"><p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed condimentum posuere massa eu commodo. Cras fermentum erat sed volutpat dignissim. Suspendisse pretium sem ut vestibulum mattis. Donec ultrices ipsum in molestie aliquam. Nulla tristique, nisl ac ultrices tempus, dolor leo convallis risus, sed porttitor magna sapien vitae neque. </p></div>
</div>






</div>
</div> <!-- End Band -->

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
}

#welcome {
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.slider{
    z-index:0;
    position: relative;
}

#logo img{
    width: 190px;
    height: 60px;
}

.band-navigation{
    background-color: #3d6430;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #28421f;
    margin: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top:0;
}


#welcome {
    margin-top:0;
}

#welcome h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#welcome h2 {
    text-align: center;
}

#navigation {
    top:0;
    background-color: #3d6430;

}

#download {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#nav {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 130px;

}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}




#welcome {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* bars.html */

.band-bars-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
}


#bars-logo{
    width: 260px;
    height: 175px;
}


.bars-box{
    background-color: #cecece;

}

.bars-box :hover{
    background-color: #000;
}


#bars-description h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#bars-description p {
    padding-left: 10px;
}

#bars-address p{
    margin: 0px;
}

/*  barsDetail.html */
#bar-logo {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#google-maps{
    margin-top: 100px;
}


/* about.html */

.band-about-content{
    margin-top: 100px;
}

#section{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#mobile-mockup-image img{
    height: 450px;
    width: 250px;
}

#newsletter-mockup-image img{
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
}

.band-about-footer{
    background-color: #3d6430;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#footer ul li{
    display: inline;
}

#footer a{
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: heavy;
}

/*
* Skeleton V1.2
* Copyright 2011, Dave Gamache
* www.getskeleton.com
* Free to use under the MIT license.
* http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
* 6/20/2012
*/

/* Table of Content
==================================================
    #Site Styles
    #Page Styles
    #Media Queries
    #Font-Face */

/* #Site Styles
================================================== */

/* #Page Styles
================================================== */

/* #Media Queries
================================================== */

    /* Smaller than standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* Tablet Portrait size to standard 960 (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {}

    /* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .band.content {
        margin-top: 140px;
    }
    }

    /* Mobile Landscape Size to Tablet Portrait (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
        .band.content {
        margin-top: 140px;
    }
    .band.bar.information{
        margin-top: 80px;
}  

.band-bars-container{
        margin-top: 150px;
    }


    #bars-description{
    margin-top: 50px;

}

    }

    /* Mobile Portrait Size to Mobile Landscape Size (devices and browsers) */
    @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        .band.content {
        margin-top: 140px;
    }
    .band.bar.information{
        margin-top: 80px;
}   
    .band-bars-container{
        margin-top: 150px;
    }


    #bars-description{
    margin-top: 50px;

}

    }


@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    .band.content {
        margin-top: 140px;
    }
    .band.bar.information{
        margin-top: 80px;
}
    .band-bars-container{
        margin-top: 150px;
    }

    #bars-description{
    margin-top: 50px;

}

}

/* #Font-Face
================================================== */
/*  This is the proper syntax for an @font-face file
        Just create a "fonts" folder at the root,
        copy your FontName into code below and remove
        comment brackets */

/*  @font-face {
        font-family: 'FontName';
        src: url('../fonts/FontName.eot');
        src: url('../fonts/FontName.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../fonts/FontName.svg#webfontZam02nTh') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal; }
*/
```